# TIMESTAMPDIFF returning extra day

Tags: mysql

Can someone explain to me why this returns 366 days and not 365 days?

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, '2019-12-27 01:00:00', '2020-12-27 01:00:00');
```

Im little bit confused by this.
Is there any correct way to show 365 days?

Comment: 2020 is a leap year

Comment: @forpas make that an answer?

Comment: @ysth there is no need. The question should be closed because there is no problem/error.